# Adjunctions and dualizable objects in symmetric monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories

Let $(C, \otimes, I)$ be a symmetric monoidal category (for example, modules over a commutative ring), and let $M$ be a dualizable object with dual $M^\vee$.
Then $\_ \otimes M$ is left adjoint to $\mathcal{H}om(M, \_) \cong M^\vee\otimes\_$. Applying the same logic to $M^\vee$, we have that $\_\otimes M^\vee$ is left adjoint to $M\otimes \_$ since $({M^\vee})^\vee\cong M$. Furthermore, since $(C, \otimes)$ is symmetric monoidal, then the functor $\_\otimes M$ is equivalent to the functor $M\otimes \_$ and similarly for $M^\vee$.

In summary, we have that $M\otimes \_$ is both left and right adjoint to $M^\vee\otimes\_ ≅\_ \otimes M^\vee$ (and $\_ \otimes M^\vee$ is both left and right adjoint to $\_ \otimes M$).

**Question 1:** what are some other examples of such situations, i.e. functor $F: C→D$ and $G: D\rightarrow C$ such that $F$ is both left and right adjoint to $G$ (and $G$ is left and right adjoint to $F$) but these are not equivalences.

**Question 2:** What happens when $(C, \otimes)$ is not symmetric monoidal?

I believe that in this case one must distinguish between a left and right dual for $M$ and the resulting functors are left/right adjoints respectively.

**Question 3:**  Can a similar situation occur when $M$ is a $R-S$-bimodule, for non-commutative rings $R,S$ and the adjoint functors are $\otimes_{R-mod} M: mod-R \rightarrow mod-S$ and $Hom_{mod-S}(M, \_): mod-S\rightarrow mod-R$.

I am  confused about what exactly the dualizability condition is.

Comment: For $1$, the relevant keyword is [ambidextrous adjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ambidextrous+adjunction). You can find some disussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377101/a-specific-property-of-bi-adjunction).